# I get a Java Security Error when I try to run the class

Tags: java, swing, spinner, jlabel

I've very new to java and am probably reaching father ahead with it than I should be trying at this point but I'm trying to learn.

I keep getting this error when trying to run my program

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the code I am trying to run

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;


public class Assingment5 extends JFrame {

public Assingment5() {
    //fonts
    java.awt.Font titlefont = new java.awt.Font("Dialog",Font.BOLD,20); 
    java.awt.Font subfont = new java.awt.Font("Dialog",Font.BOLD,14);
    java.awt.Font body = new java.awt.Font("Dialog",Font.PLAIN,12);
    //window
    setSize(1000, 800);
    this.setLayout(null);
    setTitle("If Statements Assingment");
    setLocation(350, 50);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Welcome Text
    JLabel welcomelb = new JLabel("Welcome to my assingment!");
    welcomelb.setFont(titlefont);
    welcomelb.setBounds(20, 10, 500, 30);
    add(welcomelb);
    //second set of welcome text
    JLabel subwelcome = new JLabel("There are 5 Programs to choose from:");
    subwelcome.setFont(subfont);
    subwelcome.setBounds(20, 30, 300, 30);
    add(subwelcome);





    //Question one variables

    //Question one title
    JLabel q1title = new JLabel("Question 1");
    q1title.setFont(subfont);
    q1title.setBounds(20, 70, 100, 30);
    add(q1title);
    //Question one dialog1
    JLabel q1d1 = new JLabel("Enter a number and confirm");
    q1d1.setFont(body);
    q1d1.setBounds(20, 100, 200, 30);
    add(q1d1);
    //spinner for input
    int spinnerstart = 1;
    SpinnerModel number = new SpinnerNumberModel(spinnerstart, spinnerstart - 1, spinnerstart + 50, 1);
    final JSpinner q1spin = addSpinner(this,number);
    q1spin.setBounds(20, 130, 50, 25);
    //Okay button
    JButton btconfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    //x, y, width, height
    btconfirm.setBounds(80, 130, 80, 25);
    btconfirm.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String q1output = null;
            Object q1input = q1spin.getValue();
            int q1inputINT = Integer.parseInt((String) q1input);
            if (q1inputINT <10 && q1inputINT >1) {
                q1output = "True";
            }
            else {
                q1output = "False";
            }
            //Question one output
            JLabel q1d2 = new JLabel();
            java.awt.Font subfont = new java.awt.Font("Dialog",Font.BOLD,14);
            q1d2.setFont(subfont);
            q1d2.setBounds(20, 300, 200, 30);
            q1d2.setText(q1output);
            add(q1d2);
        }
    });
    add(btconfirm);


}

static protected JSpinner addSpinner(Container c, SpinnerModel model) {
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
    c.add(spinner);

    return spinner;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assingment5 window = new Assingment5();
    window.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

I Hope I am doing this right, I just joined. Sorry if I screwed this up.

Comment: How are you trying to run this code? And on what machine?

Comment: i tried running your code in my machine using eclipse, works fine

Comment: @upog: I agree. The code has logical and semantics problems, to be sure, but it should *run* unless for some reason he's running it in a strange way or on a machine that's not allowing him to do something.

Answer (score 2):

I can run this program perfectly fine.

I only get an exception when I hit the confirm button

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Assingment5$1.actionPerformed(Assingment5.java:71)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
...
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I expect you have the same problem since the partial stacktrace you posted is from the event thread, while your `main` method does not run on the EDT. A suggestion for next time is to post the whole stack trace.

The `ClassCastException` message is rather clear:

```
Object q1input = q1spin.getValue();
int q1inputINT = Integer.parseInt((String) q1input);
```

In this code snippet the `q1input` variable is already an `Integer` and not a `String` since you are using a `SpinnerNumberModel` as model for the spinner. Just change those lines to

```
int q1inputINT = (Integer)q1spin.getValue();
```

Comment: Whoops yeah I forgot to say that it errors after the button not when it is run, sorry about that.

That fixed the problem though! Thank you very much!